# python dictionary assignment using map and lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I was just curious to know if the following loop is doable with the map() rather than using for loop ? 
If yes please be kind enough to show how ? 
or
what's the most efficient way to do the following ?

```
f = open('sample_list.txt').read().split('\n')

val =   lambda x: re.match('[a-zA-z0-9]+',x).group() if x else None

for line in f:
    if line.find('XYZ') == -1:
        dict[val(line)]=0
    else:
        dict[val(line)]=1
```

This program reads a file formatted as :

```
ABCD XYZ 
DEFG ABC
```

then creates a dicionary with first word as KEY and if the second value 
is XYZ then it will assign a value of 1 else 0.

i.e dict will be :

```
{'ABCD': 1, 'DEFG': 0}
```

**UPDATE :**

I timed the approaches suggested by **@shx2** and **@arekolek**
dictionary comprehension is faster, and **@arekolek's** approach is way faster than anything as it doesn't use the val() lambda function i declared.

the code :

```
def a():
    return {
    val(line) : 0 if line.find('XYZ') == -1 else 1
    for line in f
    }

def b():
    return dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1] == 'XYZ')), map(str.split, f)))

def c():
    return {k: int(v == 'XYZ') for k, v in map(str.split, f)}

print 'a='+timeit.timeit(a)
print 'b='+timeit.timeit(b)
print 'c='+timeit.timeit(c)
```

result :

```
a = 13.7737597283
b = 6.82668938135
c = 3.98859187269
```

Thanks both for showing this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a lambda:

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], int(x[1] == 'XYZ')), map(str.split, f)))
```

Or:

```
dict(map(lambda k, v: (k, int(v == 'XYZ')), *map(str.split, f)))
```

Dictionary comprehension:

```
{k: int(v == 'XYZ') for k, v in map(str.split, f)}
```

Answer (score 5):

Better to use [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) than `map`.

Can be done like this:

```
my_dict = {
    val(line) : 0 if line.find('XYZ') == -1 else 1
    for line in f
}
```

Some notes and improvements:

1. `dict` is not a good variable name in python
2. Alternatives to the complicated expression `0 if line.find('XYZ') == -1 else 1`:

   - `int(line.find('XYZ') != -1)` (converting `bool` to `int`)
   - if you can leave the values as `bool`s: `line.find('XYZ') != -1`
   - `'XYZ' in line` (credit: @JonClements)

Comment: Why use `str.find` at all here - `if not 'XYZ' in line` is more pythonic if you only want to check containment and aren't going to use the index...

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, this is great.